# Eliminating tab separation between two fields in tab delimited txt file

Tags: gawk

I'm trying to eliminate the tab separation between two fields in a (huge) tab delimited text file.
My data looks like this:

```
rs12345 8000    A   B
rs67890 8000    B   B
rs54321 8000    A   A
...
```

I would like to turn it into:

```
rs12345 8000    AB
rs67890 8000    BB
rs54321 8000    AA
...
```

There are several other columns (not to be modified) to the right of the two I would like to merge.

Thanks a lot to anybody who can help.

Luca

Answer (score 2):

The following should work (with bash). It sets the third field to the concatenated value of third and fourth fields and shifts the fourth field onwards one left.

```
awk -F$'\t' -v OFS=$'\t' '{$3=$3$4;for(i=4; i<NF; ++i) $i=$(i+1);NF=NF-1;print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file
rs12345 8000    A       B       test    2332
rs67890 8000    B       B       ew      45
rs54321 8000    A       A       dfdfg   34
```

Setting filed $3 to $3$4 and remove $4 and extra tab

```
awk '{$3=$3$4;$4="";sub("\t\t","\t")}1' OFS="\t" file
rs12345 8000    AB      test    2332
rs67890 8000    BB      ew      45
rs54321 8000    AA      dfdfg   34
```